# In React how can I set state variables in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a number of state variables (I am only showing 3):

```
class IntroductionPage extends React.Component<SomePageProps, {inId: string,
  i1: string,
  i2: string
}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {inId:'',
      i1:'',
      i2:''
    };
  }
```

and I am reading key-value pairs from a DB:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| start_type | field_name | start_text |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 0          | i1         | hi         |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 0          | i2         | it's me!   |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 0          | i3         | Schoon     |
+------------+------------+------------+


for (var key in response.data) {
  var dat = response.data[key];
  getStartType=dat['start_type']//JSON.stringify(dat['start_type']);
  for (var inner_key in dat) {
    console.log('key=' + inner_key + ' value=' + dat[inner_key]);
  }
```

gives

```
key=start_type value=0
key=field_name value=i1
key=start_text value=hi
...
```

Now is there any way I can loop through these retrieved value and set state, for example something like a loop or map version of this:

```
this.setState({dat['field_name']:dat['start_text']});
```

so the first row returned would be fieldname= i1, start_text ='hi' and so the loop would `setState ({i1:'hi'})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a technical question of "can I do this?" the answer is "Yes".  It is ok to call `setState` inside a loop in your example because each state update is independent of each other and does not rely on previous values of the state.  React will likely batch the `setState` updates together so that you won't have multiple re-renders.

```
for (var key in response.data) {
  var dat = response.data[key];
  this.setState({ [dat.field_name]: dat.start_text });
}
```

You use brackets around `[dat.field_name]` because it is a variable property key.  But variable property names are a problem for Typescript because it assumes that they are `string` instead of a valid key.

---

I would probably do what @Sharon Geller suggests and call `setState` once with a combined value.

```
const changes = response.data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.field_name]: curr.start_text }),
  {}
);
this.setState(changes);
```

Technically this doesn't require an assertion because the type of `changes` is the empty object `{}`, but you might want to assert a type on the initial value `{} as State`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. However I get `Parameter 'prev' implicitly has an 'any' type.`  Any idea why?

Comment: What is `prev`?

Comment: oh, sorry I changed the name of `acc`.

Comment: It should get the type of the initial value which is `{}`.  If you want a different type you can assert the type of the initial value like `{} as State`.  The [docs on array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) might help?

Answer (score 3):

> ### React Docs:
>
> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be >batched for performance gains

don't call setState in a loop,
just update a local variable inside aloop and then call the setSate method on that variable it will save you some rerenders